# How to change the stripe settings of the account through the api?

Tags: stripe-payments

I need manage Stripe Settins using API.

In this section ([Subscriptions and emails](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic)) there is an opportunity to manage the sending of emails to customers. I need to change the positions "Send emails about upcoming renewals", "Send emails about expiring cards" and others using api requests. Without using webhooks. Only true/false

I will be grateful for your answers

Comment: Those settings, https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic on Subscriptions and Emails are only supported via the Dashboard and not the API. This is true to most settings.

Comment: I would add that the 'Send emails about expiring cards' feature is most likely not useful to anyone anymore, since it very likely rests on the `customer.source.expiring`, which only works for Source tokens, not the new Payment Methods ones